# I can´t install rcov, makefile warning 124 and 130

Tags: ruby, rubygems, makefile

I can´t install the rcov gem ;-(
I use BitNami Redmine, Windows 7.

```
gem install rcov
```

Result:

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rcov:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Program Files/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:130: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Program'
Makefile:124: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Program'
Makefile:130: warning: overriding commands for target `Files/BitNami'
Makefile:124: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Files/BitNami'
Makefile:130: warning: overriding commands for target `Redmine'
Makefile:124: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Redmine'
make: *** No rule to make target `ruby.h', needed by `callsite.o'.  Stop.

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/l
ib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rcov-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Program Files/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/
gems/rcov-1.0.0/ext/rcovrt/gem_make.out
```

Before this message BitNami told me to install the DevKit. I installed the DevKit, did edit the confiy.yml (- C:/Program Files/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby -- maybe this was my fault because I don´t wrote the "") and startet the DevKit installation. Everything was fine but it´s not possible to install the gem. In my opinion it was a very bad idea to install Redmine into a folder with spaces.

I searched for a solution but none solution did work ;-(

Solution 1: I substed the BitNami path to X, tried the installation but that didn´t work.
Solution 2: Use the Microsoft C++ Express advice (http://minimalbugs.com/questions/how-to-install-gem-rcov-on-windows)
Solution 3: An older version of rcov (like 0.9.11) also didn´t work

If I try to install the rdiscount gem I got a similar error (Makefile 130 / 124 / ... C:/Program/...).

Now I need help ;-)

My gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
actionpack (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
activeresource (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
activesupport (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
addressable (2.2.8)
after_commit (1.0.10)
allison (2.0.3)
arel (3.0.2)
aws-sdk (1.5.5, 1.5.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
bluecloth (2.1.0 x86-mingw32)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.1.4, 1.0.21)
capistrano (2.12.0, 2.9.0)
capybara (1.1.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
childprocess (0.3.3)
coderay (1.0.7, 1.0.6)
crack (0.3.1)
cucumber (1.2.1, 0.9.4)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0, 0.3.2)
daemons (1.1.8, 1.0.10)
delayed_job (3.0.3, 2.0.7)
diff-lcs (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
echoe (4.5.6)
edavis10-object_daddy (0.4.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
fastercsv (1.5.5, 1.5.4)
ffi (1.0.9 x86-mingw32)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gemcutter (0.7.1)
gherkin (2.11.1 x86-mingw32, 2.2.9 x86-mingw32)
gruff (0.3.6)
highline (1.6.13, 1.6.8)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (3.0.6, 2.12.4)
hpricot (0.8.5 i386-mswin32)
httparty (0.8.3, 0.8.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
json (1.4.6 x86-mingw32)
json_pure (1.7.3, 1.6.3)
libwebsocket (0.1.3)
mail (2.4.4)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19, 1.18)
mini_magick (3.4, 3.3)
mocha (0.11.4, 0.10.5)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
mongrel_service (0.4.0)
multi_json (1.3.6, 1.1.0)
multi_xml (0.5.1, 0.4.1)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
needle (1.3.0)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.5.2, 2.2.1)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32, 1.5.0 x86-mingw32, 1.4.4 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prototype-rails (3.2.1)
rack (1.4.1, 1.1.3)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.2.6, 2.3.14)
rails_analyzer_tools (1.4.0)
railties (3.2.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rake-compiler (0.8.1, 0.7.9)
rdoc (3.12, 3.11)
RedCloth (4.2.9 x86-mingw32)
riddle (1.5.2, 1.5.0)
rmagick (2.12.0)
rspec (2.10.0, 2.7.0)
rspec-core (2.10.1, 2.7.1)
rspec-expectations (2.10.0, 2.7.0)
rspec-mocks (2.10.1, 2.7.0)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.24.0)
simplecov (0.6.4)
simplecov-html (0.5.3)
sprockets (2.4.3, 2.1.3, 2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32, 1.3.5 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
subexec (0.2.2, 0.1.0)
SyslogLogger (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
thin (1.3.1)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.12, 1.4.10)
thor (0.15.3, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.5)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uuidtools (2.1.2)
webrat (0.7.3)
xpath (0.1.4)
yard (0.8.2.1, 0.8.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Everything solved it self by changing the installation location of the Bitnami Redmine Stack. Default location is C:\Program Files\Bitnami Redmine Stack\

The "make" which is included in the DevKit can't handle spaces in the pathname.
I installed the bitnami stack to C:\BitNamiRedmine\ and now everything works perfectly.

1. Install Bitname Redmine to a path without spaces, e.g. `C:\BitNamiRedmine\`
2. Download the Ruby Development Kit -> http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
3. Extract the DevKit to C:\BitNamiRedmine\ruby\devkit\
4. `use_redmine.bat`
5. `cd ruby\devkit`
6. run `ruby dk.rb init`
7. add »`- "C:/BitNamiRedmine/ruby"`« (without »«, Important: Forward-Slashes!) to the config.yml in the DevKit folder
8. run `ruby dk.rb install`
9. Done!

Now you can navigate to your apps/redmine/htdocs folder and run `gem install rcov`.
Tested on Windows Server 2008 R2.